# crc16: получаю один байт вместо двух

Tags: c++

Подскажите, в чем ошибка: пытаюсь получить суму CCITT, использую функцию, показанную ниже, но по какой-то причине функция отдает только 1 байт вместо 2 (значение верное, но неполное).

```
unsigned short crc16(char* data, short len){ 
    unsigned char x;
    short crc = 0xFFFF;
    while (len--){
        x = crc >> 8 ^ *data++;
        x ^= x>>4;
        crc = (crc << 8) ^ (x << 12) ^ (x << 5) ^ x;
    }

    return crc;
}

char* test = new char[0x0];
      test[0] = 0xBB;
      test[1] = 0xBB;

unsigned short = crc16(test, 2); // получается 0x48, должно быть 0xС948
```

С одной стороны, в javascript получаю 0xС948; с другой стороны - в c++ получаю 0x48.

Comment: Вы точно создаете нулевой длины массив `test`? :) Кстати, VC++ 2015 дает 0xС948...

Comment: длина судя по всему не влияет, скомпилировал под x86 через g++ все отлично выдает - C948, а когда прошиваю тот-же сорс на atmega328p выдает только 48, думаю про комментарий x << 12 пока сложно мне эти сдвиги даются )

Comment: @user21736, вы уверены что ваш unsigned char на атмеге занимает 2 байта?

Comment: и действительно (x << 12) у меня 0x0000 на железке, а на компьютере корректно все 0x40000 и 0x48000

Comment: sizeof(unsegned short) на железке выдает 2 байта ? может у вас размерность слова там другая

Comment: @D-side с чего Вы решили, что `(x << 12)` всегда 0? Тут будет продвижение `x` до `int`, и может быть `UB` если вдруг `int` окажется меньше 12 бит (в чём я лично оч.сомневаюсь). А наиболее очевидная проблема кода - запись за границами массива `test`. Зачем тут динамическое выделение памяти вообще непонятно, можно просто `unsigned char test[] = { 0xBB, 0xBB };`

Comment: @alexolut ошибся. Почему-то полагал, что тип результата совпадает с типом левого операнда (но это ж плюсы!), который, скорее всего, меньше 12 бит. Да, с продвижением до `unsigned int` не всегда будет 0. Дезинформацию грохнул.